# Firebase Storage upload fails with unknown error on Windows Phone

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, firebase, windows-phone-8.1, firebase-storage

I have a project uploading photos to Firebase Storage.

Everything is working fine on Desktop Browsers, and on iPhone but When it comes to Windows phone I don't understand why it is not working.

I listen to "state_changed" and alert the progress of uploading as I don't know how to debug in a console.

So when it reaches around 43% of upload task, it throws an error but not helpfull at all :

> Firebase Storage: An unknown error occurred, please check the error payload for server response

What can I do to find out what is this error ? Or what can I do to make this work ?

Comment: Is there an additional error in the payload you can share with us?

Comment: Well I don't know how to get the payload... Can you explain to me ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this ploblem as well and it worked after adding the whitelist plugin

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```